Ubuntu Server 22.04 installation from command line
I'd like to create a ubuntu server 22.04 with the root and boot on an ssd raid 1 without encryption and a raid 6 with 10 drives with luks encryption.
How can i do this from a command prompt?
Thanks in advance
